# Debug via breakpoint, Xcode subproject

Tags: xcode, debugging

So, we're talking Xcode 6.2 and the year 2015 - apart from most articles on the web.

I have an iOS project that contains two dependency projects that I need to debug into. I have tried various tutorials and articles from the web with no luck. How can I actually debug the code from the sub projects?

In the frameworks folder of the parent project I have included compiled versions of these sub projects? Perhaps these are what are being used and Xcode ignores the actual source code.

My project is setup as shown below, you can see there are two sub projects (SDK & Server connector). The compiled versions of these projects (.framework) have also been included in the main projects Frameworks folder (for successful build).

Any ideas?

[image: My project setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is this article:

[Sub projects in Xcode](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/12/sub-projects-in-xcode/)

Basically, for each dependency you must create a static library target and reference that target in the dependent project under "Build Phases".

**GOTCHA 1:** Categories weren't working out of the box for me. To fix this I needed to go to the parent project that references the libraries -> Targets -> Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags = "-ObjC".

**GOTCHA 2:** You may get "file not found" errors for headers you are importing. You will need to use Angle Brackets for the headers located in the libraries e.g.

```
#import <FancyLibrary.h>
```

As well as including the path to the library in the "Header Search Path" of the parent project. i.e. Targets -> Build Settings -> Header Search Paths. (I set it to the root of the project and marked as recursive).